# How can I add legends in the ClusteringComponents function?

Tags: legending, cluster-analysis, segmentation

I am trying to do color separation on this [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pipm06szq2cw4gn/beads.png?dl=0) using ClusteringComponents function (following an example on Wolfram Mathematica [webpage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html)). I will like to have a legend identifying each segmented component as "a" to "e". For example, using the original code,

```
ClusteringComponents[image, 5] // Colorize
```

I could group black and green beads as "dark green->a". However, if I replace 5 with 6, I should be able to separate black from green beads so that I now have a legend like:
Grey->"a"
dark green->"b"
and so on!

You kind suggestions and recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Happy Holidays guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the `ColorRules` option for `Colorize` and creating a legend.

```
colorRules = Thread[Range[7] -> Table[RandomColor[], 7]]

legend = SwatchLegend[Values@colorRules, Keys@colorRules]

Legended[Colorize[ClusteringComponents[image, 7], 
  ColorRules -> colorRules], legend]
```

[image]
[image]

(replacing `Keys@colorRules` with `{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}` would change the labels from numbers to those letters, of course)

You can use different colour schemes from `ColorData` like so:

```
colorRules = 
 Thread[Range[7] -> Table[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 7}}][n], {n, 7}]]
```

(using the second argument to set a min/max for the scale - you can avoid having to do that if you use an `"Indexed"` color scheme. Check the `ColorData` docs for more)

or with the function `Hue` like so:

```
colorRules = 
 Thread[Range[7] -> Table[Hue[Rescale[n, {0, 7}]], {n, 7}]]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I really appreciate this. Is it possible to replace "RandomColor" with some colorfunction such as "Hue"?

Comment: Yep, see my edit.